# How to validate a laravel token using python?

Tags: python, php, laravel, oauth-2.0

The current architecture of my project is as follows
[image]

I am using Laravel Passport to generate the access tokens, in the Laravel application I have all the routes protected by the middleware that Laravel provides me and I can verify that the token is valid, however how could I verify that the same token is valid in python ? both projects shared the same database

I want to avoid having to make a request to laravel to verify that the token is valid, should I create a middleware in python that does the same thing as laravel passport? or is there a library that allows verifying the access token with python.

I am attentive to any suggestion.

Comment: do you have access to the database from python which have laravel ??

Comment: Yes I have access to the same database